# Convert binary to signed decimal

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal, signed

I'd like to convert a binary vector to a signed decimal in matlab using the classic functions.

I have a vector `byte = [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]`,

if I convert it to decimal with `byte = bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')` I get 130, but if I insert this byte in a calculator I get -126, ergo signed.

I tried `byte = typecast(bi2de(byte, 'left-msb'), 'int32')`, but failed miserably.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
>> typecast(uint8(bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')), 'int8')

ans =

 -126
```

Comment: so the problem was if i did 'uint32'? can't i extract it to 32 bits without ruining the value and connotation

Comment: I guess so. If you want it in signed int 32, you should cast to `uint32` first (to convert the array), then `typecast` to `int32` to make it signed.

Comment: I'm reading bytes and converting them in dec from a file like this:
byte = de2bi(fread(fr, 1), 32, 'right-msb')
byte = typecast(uint32(bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')), 'int32')
If byte is 13 i should get -1.3422e+09, but i get 1342177280

Comment: and if i remove the type cast and do
byte = de2bi(fread(fr, 1), 32, 'right-msb')
byte = bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')

I get 1.3422e+09 so i'm missing a minus

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're reading the file with `fread(fr, 1)`, so one `byte` at a time. You want to convert it to `int32`, is that right?

Comment: I'm doing CRC32. I need to read a byte, flip it(like fliplr) an then expand it to 32 bits. So if a byte is 13, then you get in binary 0101  0000...0000 and in dec -1.3422e+09

Comment: Try reading your byte like this `byte = [de2bi(fread(fr, 1), 8, 'right-msb') zeros(1, 24)]`

Comment: ok, how do i convert it to decimal then, because if i do `byte = bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')` i get `2.9528e+09`(from 13)

Comment: and if i `byte = typecast(uint32(bi2de(byte, 'left-msb')), 'int32')` i get  `-1342177280`

Comment: But I thought [you said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451285/convert-binary-to-signed-decimal/23451513?noredirect=1#comment35961061_23451513) you wanted to get dec -1.3422e+09 in the end (for byte = 13), right? That's what you got (-1342177280). Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: oh, is that the same? didn't know that, sorry

Comment: Yeah, it's just that `-1.3422e+09` is in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Answer (score 0):

do you need to do it in one line?  If you know it is going to be interpreted as unsigned, you could just catch values greater than 127 in an if statement.

```
if (byte > 127)
    byte = byte - 256;
end
```